# How to Implement Argon2 Hash on OpenLdap?

Tags: hash, openldap, bitnami, argon2-ffi

[Argon2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2#:%7E:text=Argon2%20est%20une%20fonction%20de,sous%20licence%20Creative%20Commons%20CC0.) is a password hashing algorithm that was selected as the winner of the Password Hashing Competition in July 2015. It is a secure and efficient algorithm that is resistant to brute-force attacks.

I am currently using **OpenLdap v2.5 packaged as [bitnami/openldap](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/openldap/)** image to store user information, including passwords. **I would like to implement Argon2 to hash passwords so that I can help to protect them from being compromised**.

Specifically, I need to know:

- How to install the argon2 module on OpenLdap ?
- How to configure OpenLdap to use Argon2 for password hashing ?
- How to test my configuration to make sure that it is working correctly ?

Answer (score 3):

To implement Argon2 Hash on OpenLDAP, you can do the following steps:

1. Add Argon2 as OpenLdap hash module & allowed method
2. Create/Modify userpassword with Argon2
3. Verify user authentication

### 1 - Add Argon2 as OpenLdap hash module & allowed method

Modify LDAP config in order to load Argon2

```bash
ldapmodify -H -Y EXTERNAL ldapi:/// -f modules.ldif
```

with modules.ldif:

```
# Load Argon2 module
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{0}
# Adapt the olcModulePath below depending on your OS or your packaged openldap
olcModulePath: /opt/bitnami/openldap/libexec/openldap/
olcModuleLoad: argon2.so

# Tell that Argon2 is an allowed hash method
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcPasswordHash
olcPasswordHash: {ARGON2}
```

### 2 - Create/Modify userpassword with Argon2

Generate a hashed password with Argon2 module

```bash
slappasswd -o module-load=argon2.so -h {ARGON2} -s "mypassword"
```

It should return something like : `{ARGON2}$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$G+lDOYm0ra9Gl/e/gZ+FZw$HlePGPXj2ghUZfznIvKvzgRZaEXm0/4YVWttmztakgM`

Then, modify an existing user password:

```bash
ldapmodify -x -H ldapi:/// -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w "adminPassword" -x -f changeUserPassword.ldif
```

with `changeUserPassword.ldif`:

```
dn: cn=JohnDoe,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: {ARGON2}$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$G+lDOYm0ra9Gl/e/gZ+FZw$HlePGPXj2ghUZfznIvKvzgRZaEXm0/4YVWttmztakgM
```

## 3 -  Verify user authentication

Now, verify that the user can be authenticated with his new hashed password:

```bash
ldapwhoami -x -H ldapi:/// -D  "cn=JohnDoe,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com" -w "mypassword"
```

If ìt is ok, it should return the DN : `dn:cn=JohnDoe,,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.